# ASP c# web application error in using dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dll, dllimport

I am trying to import a dll in c# web application. Steps i followed:

1. Go to Add reference in projects and browse for the dll and select OK
2. In code behind, add line "using mydll;"

I am able to see most of functions and variables but some are missing. I tried the same method in VB web app and its working fine there. Below is my code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using PPDSDUALLib; <-- My dll imported.

PPDSDUALLib.Property oProp;
oProp = oComp.Property[i]; <-- error line, Component doesn't contain definition for Property.
```

But the same is working properly in VB web application.

EDITING:

Thanks to all for the replies.

I viewed the detail structure in "Object browser" and got to know that 'Property' is the default value of oComp so it is not visible in c#.
I think there is difference in the way in which c# and VB import the dlls(not so sure about this). VB shows the default properties, whereas c# converts it to index. I was able to display just the first value using

```
oComp[0].Name;
```

But if I change index to anything other than 0, it is giving an error. Please help.

Comment: When do you get this error? during compilation or execution?

Comment: Are you sure a `PPDSDUALLib.Property` also has a `Property` array?

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be on `oProp`, but on `oComp` instead.

Comment: My VB code which does the same as above, Dim oProp As [Property] oProp = oComp.Property(i)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was error in typeof variable.

It had to be of custom defined enum type rather than int.

Code below is right one:

```
for (i = 0; i < oComp.PropertyCount-1; i++)
        {
            j = (enum_type)i;

            String name = oComp[j].Name;
            s = name;

            Debug.WriteLine("Name = " + s);

        }//end of for
```

Thanks for all the replies.